# Unexpected output from the interval function

Tags: group-by, intervals, dolphindb

I used the following script to group data by time intervals of 2 seconds and calculate the last value of "contract" and "price" for each sliding window of 2 seconds:

```
t=table(2021.01.01T01:00:00+(1..5 join 9..11) as time, take(`CLF1,8) as contract, 50..57 as price)
select last(contract) as contract, last(price) as price from t group by interval(time, 2s,"prev")
```

[image]

However, the first window calculation starts from 00:00 instead of 00:01 as I anticipated. How should I modify the script to achieve the expected output: 00:00--> NAN, 00:02-->51, 00:04-->53, 00:06-->54, 00:08-->54, 00:10-->56? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *origin* parameter is not specified, the `interval` function in DolphinDB will round the starting value of the first window based on *explicitOffset* (which defaults to be false). According to [interval — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/SQLStatements/interval.html#interval), when *explicitOffset* = false, the first window starts at the nearest point t0 that is divisible by step before the starting time “t1“ (00:01 in this example). The *step* value defaults to the same as *duration* (2s), so "t0" becomes 00:00.

To ensure the starting time of the first window is 00:01, you can try the following two methods:

**Method 1:**

Adjust the windows to be left-open and right-closed by specifying `closed='right'`:

```
t=table(2021.01.01T01:00:00+(1..5 join 9..11) as time, take(`CLF1,8) as contract, 50..57 as price)
select last(contract) as contract, last(price) as price from t group by interval(time, 2s,"prev", closed='right', label='right')
```

[image]

**Method 2:**

Specify `origin='start'` to ensure the intervals start at the first value, which is a more flexible approach without being affected by the rounding rule.

```
t=table(2021.01.01T01:00:00+(1..5 join 9..11) as time, take(`CLF1,8) as contract, 50..57 as price)
select last(contract) as contract, last(price) as price from t group by interval(time, 2s,"prev", origin='start')
```

[image]